# Pygame moving sprite coordinates after an event

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've been trying to make a football game with pygame, and almost finished successfully, however, I have a few issues. I am  trying to move the ball after a goal is scored.I have tried moving the ball to the ball_x and ball_y coordinates, but it doesn't work.  My code is below, I really hope someone could edit my code so it works.

```
import pygame
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.init()


WIDTH = 1150
HEIGHT = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Images.
bgImg = pygame.image.load("Football_pitch.png")
REDGOAL = pg.Surface((50, 150), pg.SRCALPHA)
REDGOAL.fill((255, 0, 0))
redgoal_rect = REDGOAL.get_rect(topleft=(0, 340))
redgoal_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(REDGOAL)
BLUEGOAL = pg.Surface((50, 150), pg.SRCALPHA)
BLUEGOAL.fill((0, 0, 255))
bluegoal_rect = REDGOAL.get_rect(topleft=(1100, 340))
bluegoal_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(REDGOAL)


BLUECAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, (0, 0, 255), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50,10), (0, 0)])
bluecar = BLUECAR_ORIGINAL
REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 0), (50, 10), (50, 20), (0, 30)])
redcar = REDCAR_ORIGINAL

score = 0
redspeed = 7
bluespeed = 7
ball_x = 575
ball_y = 400
dx = 0
dy = 0
x = 800
y = 500



BALL = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(BALL, [0,0,0], [15, 15], 15)
# Ball variables.
ball_pos = Vector2(ball_x, ball_y)
ballrect = BALL.get_rect(center=ball_pos)
ball_vel = Vector2(dx, dy)
ball_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(BALL)
# Car variables.
pos_red = Vector2(x,y)
vel_red = Vector2(redspeed,0)
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
redangle = 180
pos_blue = Vector2(275,300)
vel_blue = Vector2(bluespeed,0)
bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
blueangle = 0
# Masks.
mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)
mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
mask_ball = pygame.mask.from_surface(BALL)
ballrect = BALL.get_rect(center=ball_pos)
vel_red.rotate_ip(-180)

def redgoal():
        print("Red Goal!!!")
        ball_x = 300
        ball_y = 300

def bluegoal():
        print("Blue Goal!!!")
        boostedspeedred = 10


run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    if y <0:
        y = 10
    if y > 450:
        y = 440
    if x > 480:
        x = 470



    if ballrect.top < 0 and ball_vel.y < 0:
        ball_vel.y *= -1
    elif ballrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and ball_vel.y > 0:
        ball_vel.y *= -1
    if ballrect.left < 0 and ball_vel.x < 0:
        ball_vel.x *= -1
    elif ballrect.right > screen.get_width() and ball_vel.x > 0:
        ball_vel.x *= -1

    if redrect.top < 0 and redrect.y < 0:
        redrect.y *= +10
    elif redrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and redrect.y > 0:
        redrect.y *= -10
    if redrect.left < 0 and redrect.x < 0:
        redrect.x *= -10
    elif redrect.right > screen.get_width() and redrect.x > 0:
        redrect.x *= -10

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        redangle += 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(-5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        # We need a new mask after the rotation.
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        redangle -= 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        redspeed == 10



    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        blueangle += 5
        vel_blue.rotate_ip(-5)
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
        bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=bluerect.center)
        mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        blueangle -= 5
        vel_blue.rotate_ip(5)
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
        bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=bluerect.center)
        mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)


    # Move the cars.
    pos_red += vel_red
    redrect.center = pos_red
    pos_blue += vel_blue
    bluerect.center = pos_blue
    # Move the ball.
    ball_vel *= .99  # Friction.
    ball_pos += ball_vel
    ballrect.center = ball_pos

    # Red car collision.
    # We need the offset between the redrect and the ballrect.
    offset_red = redrect[0] - ballrect[0], redrect[1] - ballrect[1]
    # Pass the offset to the `overlap` method. If the masks collide,
    # overlap will return a single point, otherwise `None`.
    overlap_red = mask_ball.overlap(mask_red, offset_red)
    # Blue car collision.
    offset_blue = bluerect[0] - ballrect[0], bluerect[1] - ballrect[1]
    overlap_blue = mask_ball.overlap(mask_blue, offset_blue)
    offset = redgoal_rect[0] - ballrect[0], redgoal_rect[1] - ballrect[1]
    redgoaloverlap = ball_mask.overlap(redgoal_mask, offset)
    offset = bluegoal_rect[0] - ballrect[0], bluegoal_rect[1] - ballrect[1]
    bluegoaloverlap = ball_mask.overlap(bluegoal_mask, offset)

    if redgoaloverlap:
        redgoal()
    if bluegoaloverlap:
        bluegoal()

    if overlap_red and overlap_blue:  # Both collide with the ball.
        # Not sure what should happen here.
        ball_vel = vel_red + vel_blue * 1.4
    elif overlap_red:  # Red collides with the ball.
        ball_vel = Vector2(vel_red) * 1.4
    elif overlap_blue:  # Blue collides with the ball.
        ball_vel = Vector2(vel_blue) * 1.4




    # Drawing.
    screen.blit(bgImg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(BALL, ballrect)
    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)
    screen.blit(bluecar, bluerect)
    screen.blit(REDGOAL, redgoal_rect)
    screen.blit(BLUEGOAL, bluegoal_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `ball_x`, and `ball_y`, but these the ball isn't being drawn at these locations. The ball is actually being draw at the co-ordinates in the vector called `ball_pos`.

**To fix this problem**:

1. As you might guess, there is a very simple solution: just reset `ball_pos`, instead.
2. Also, I reset the vector `ball_vel`, so the ball doesn't move after it is moved to the center again.

You might want to add in code which resets the position of the cars, too. Also, the ball is only reset if there is a "red goal".

Here is the fixed code:

```
import pygame
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.init()


WIDTH = 1150
HEIGHT = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Images.
bgImg = pygame.image.load("Football_pitch.png")
REDGOAL = pg.Surface((50, 150), pg.SRCALPHA)
REDGOAL.fill((255, 0, 0))
redgoal_rect = REDGOAL.get_rect(topleft=(0, 340))
redgoal_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(REDGOAL)
BLUEGOAL = pg.Surface((50, 150), pg.SRCALPHA)
BLUEGOAL.fill((0, 0, 255))
bluegoal_rect = REDGOAL.get_rect(topleft=(1100, 340))
bluegoal_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(REDGOAL)


BLUECAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, (0, 0, 255), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50,10), (0, 0)])
bluecar = BLUECAR_ORIGINAL
REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (255, 0, 0), [(0, 0), (50, 10), (50, 20), (0, 30)])
redcar = REDCAR_ORIGINAL

score = 0
redspeed = 7
bluespeed = 7
ball_x = 575
ball_y = 400
dx = 0
dy = 0
x = 800
y = 500



BALL = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(BALL, [0,0,0], [15, 15], 15)
# Ball variables.
ball_pos = Vector2(ball_x, ball_y)
ballrect = BALL.get_rect(center=ball_pos)
ball_vel = Vector2(dx, dy)
ball_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(BALL)
# Car variables.
pos_red = Vector2(x,y)
vel_red = Vector2(redspeed,0)
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
redangle = 180
pos_blue = Vector2(275,300)
vel_blue = Vector2(bluespeed,0)
bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=pos_red)
blueangle = 0
# Masks.
mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)
mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
mask_ball = pygame.mask.from_surface(BALL)
ballrect = BALL.get_rect(center=ball_pos)
vel_red.rotate_ip(-180)

def redgoal():
        print("Red Goal!!!")
        ball_vel.x = 0
        ball_vel.y = 0
        ball_pos.x = 575
        ball_pos.y = 400



def bluegoal():
        print("Blue Goal!!!")
        boostedspeedred = 10


run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    if y <0:
        y = 10
    if y > 450:
        y = 440
    if x > 480:
        x = 470



    if ballrect.top < 0 and ball_vel.y < 0:
        ball_vel.y *= -1
    elif ballrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and ball_vel.y > 0:
        ball_vel.y *= -1
    if ballrect.left < 0 and ball_vel.x < 0:
        ball_vel.x *= -1
    elif ballrect.right > screen.get_width() and ball_vel.x > 0:
        ball_vel.x *= -1

    if redrect.top < 0 and redrect.y < 0:
        redrect.y *= +10
    elif redrect.bottom > screen.get_height() and redrect.y > 0:
        redrect.y *= -10
    if redrect.left < 0 and redrect.x < 0:
        redrect.x *= -10
    elif redrect.right > screen.get_width() and redrect.x > 0:
        redrect.x *= -10

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        redangle += 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(-5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        # We need a new mask after the rotation.
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        redangle -= 5
        vel_red.rotate_ip(5)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
        redrect = redcar.get_rect(center=redrect.center)
        mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        redspeed == 10



    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        blueangle += 5
        vel_blue.rotate_ip(-5)
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
        bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=bluerect.center)
        mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        blueangle -= 5
        vel_blue.rotate_ip(5)
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(BLUECAR_ORIGINAL, blueangle)
        bluerect = bluecar.get_rect(center=bluerect.center)
        mask_blue = pygame.mask.from_surface(bluecar)


    # Move the cars.
    pos_red += vel_red
    redrect.center = pos_red
    pos_blue += vel_blue
    bluerect.center = pos_blue
    # Move the ball.
    ball_vel *= .99  # Friction.
    ball_pos += ball_vel
    ballrect.center = ball_pos

    # Red car collision.
    # We need the offset between the redrect and the ballrect.
    offset_red = redrect[0] - ballrect[0], redrect[1] - ballrect[1]
    # Pass the offset to the `overlap` method. If the masks collide,
    # overlap will return a single point, otherwise `None`.
    overlap_red = mask_ball.overlap(mask_red, offset_red)
    # Blue car collision.
    offset_blue = bluerect[0] - ballrect[0], bluerect[1] - ballrect[1]
    overlap_blue = mask_ball.overlap(mask_blue, offset_blue)
    offset = redgoal_rect[0] - ballrect[0], redgoal_rect[1] - ballrect[1]
    redgoaloverlap = ball_mask.overlap(redgoal_mask, offset)
    offset = bluegoal_rect[0] - ballrect[0], bluegoal_rect[1] - ballrect[1]
    bluegoaloverlap = ball_mask.overlap(bluegoal_mask, offset)

    if redgoaloverlap:
        redgoal()
    if bluegoaloverlap:
        bluegoal()

    if overlap_red and overlap_blue:  # Both collide with the ball.
        # Not sure what should happen here.
        ball_vel = vel_red + vel_blue * 1.4
    elif overlap_red:  # Red collides with the ball.
        ball_vel = Vector2(vel_red) * 1.4
    elif overlap_blue:  # Blue collides with the ball.
        ball_vel = Vector2(vel_blue) * 1.4




    # Drawing.
    screen.blit(bgImg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(BALL, ballrect)
    screen.blit(redcar, redrect)
    screen.blit(bluecar, bluerect)
    screen.blit(REDGOAL, redgoal_rect)
    screen.blit(BLUEGOAL, bluegoal_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```